# How do I write the opposite of a rational number?

Tags: rational-numbers

Write the opposite of each rational number

A)$ 9$

B)$-17.6$

C) $6.12
$

D) $-7 \frac{5}{7 }$

Some one please help! I am not doing very good in Math I'm in grade 9 and I'm struggling I would highly appreciate if someone would help me out. Thanks for taking your time to read this:)

Comment: The opposite of a number means change its sign. So a positive becomes negative and vice versa

Comment: So like 9 would be -9 now?

Comment: Yes, the opposite of 9 is -9

Comment: Thanks so much I really appreciate your help!!:)

Comment: You have butchered your own post. Your initial question was fine (though your title needed work), but butchering posts is *highly* discouraged by this community. It makes us unwilling to help.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, just as quotative "like".

Comment: Sorry I just feel that it didn't make sense but other people may not feel the same sorry

Comment: It's my first time ever using this and I needed some help because I'm clueless on this new lesson so if I discouraged anyone on here I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the sign. Remember, if there is no sign shown, it's positive. (I like to say there is an invisible $+$ sign.)

So, if the value is +'ve, it becomes -'ve; and -'ve becomes +'ve.

*Note that finding the opposite is the same as multiplying by $-1$.*